# Present UserControl.Resources

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

In my Xaml I have defined a resource as vehicleDataInput which presents some textboxes for user to input data. If I don't define a x:Key for it it will present itself in my app and works as it should. Problem is I want to decide were in my view it is placed with the help of a x:Key but I can't get the binding correct.

You can see in my code further down that I have tried with a content control and binding to "vehicleDataInput" but it does not work at runtime.

I have tried to find an answer to this problem but noone seems to have it which makes me think I`m aproaching this problem the wrong way, what have I missed?

```
<UserControl x:Class="RegCarManager.Vehicles.CreateVehicle.CreateVehicleView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:vehicles="clr-namespace:RegCarManager.Vehicles"
         xmlns:vehiclesViewModel="clr-namespace:RegCarManager.Vehicles.CreateVehicle"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">


<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="vehicleDataInput" DataType="{x:Type vehicles:VehicleModel}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Model" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Model}" Margin="5" Width="150" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Reg number" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding RegNumber}" Margin="5" Width="150" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>


<DockPanel Margin="20">
    <ComboBox   DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
                SelectedValuePath="ClientId"
                SelectedValue="{Binding OwnerId, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource vehicleDataInput}" />

    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Button Content="Save" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="10,2" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Command="{Binding Path=SaveNewVehicleCommand}" IsDefault="True" Width="100" />
    </DockPanel>

    <ContentControl Margin="20,10" Content="{Binding Path=NewVehicle}" />
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Does your viewmodel have a property of type `VehicleModel`? Where is the `VehicleModel` you want to display in your ContentControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template is used to generate UI which displays content. It isn't the content; it's a description of how the content should be presented to the user.

```
<ContentControl
    Content="{Binding NewVehicle}"
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource vehicleDataInput}" 
    />
```

I'm guessing that you must have an instance of `VehicleModel` somewhere in your main viewmodel. Is that what `NewVehicle` is?

It doesn't really matter in this case whether you use `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource`. The difference is just that if you replace the `vehicleDataInput` resource in the resource dictionary with a different template at runtime, `DynamicResource` will be watching out for that and will update the `ContentControl`. But you won't be doing that, so `StaticResource` is fine.

Comment: Yes NewVehicle was the property I used to provide the model and with you piece of code it worked as it should. I also want to thank you for taking the time to explain some around static and dynamic resource.